# Connecting TFS-2015 update 3 which has (kerberos Authentication) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, tfs-2015

I try to connect TFS-2015 (kerberos Authentication)
I am using below JS-Code , but it didnt work :(

```
$.ajax({
url:
"https://<server>/<collection>/_apis/wit/workitems/api-version=3.0",
type: 'GET',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
}
}).done(function(data){ 
console.log('done');
console.log(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus ,errorThrown){
console.log('error'); console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

Any one can help mehelp me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with your code, it works at my side with Internet Explorer. If you see any issue with chrome, check this link for details: [jQuery ajax requests with Kerberos Authentication](http://webkort.blogspot.com/2014/11/jquery-ajax-requests-with-kerberos.html).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var query = { "query": "Select [System.Id] from WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = 'TeamProjectName' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'" };    
$.ajax({
url: "http://tfsserver/collectionname/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0",
type: 'Post',
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: "json",   
data: JSON.stringify(query),
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
}
}).done(function(data){
alert('done');
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus ,errorThrown){
alert('error'); 
alert(errorThrown);
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer
if i want to get a specific workitem 
can u help me which Code i should add to my Code

Comment: @yahya.müll Just use the url in your code, the only issue in the URL is that you missed the workitem id in the url. The URL should be "https://<server>/<collection>/_apis/wit/workitems/workitemid/api-version=3.0". For more information, you can refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-work-item

Comment: please see the code and the image i posted now
thank u alot

Comment: @yahya.müll It seems that you want to query the workitems via wiql, please see my updated answer for details.

Comment: shlout the Type be 'POST' or 'GET' ?

Comment: @yahya.müll If you just want to get a workitem with workitem id, use "Get", if you want to send a query fo tfs server to query workitems, use "Post". You can refer to the details in the link I sent you before.

Comment: thank u alot
is this code also work for TFS-2015 version 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                var d = { "query": "Select [System.Id] from WorkItem
                 Where [System.TeamProject] = '@MR' AND
                [System.WorkItemType] = 'Defect'" }; 
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "https://<server>/tfs/<collection>",
                cache: false,
             async: true,
 xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
 },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),

            success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('POSTED SUCCESSFULLY TO THE SERVER');
                    },
            error: function (msg, url, line) {

                        alert(msg);
                        alert(url);
                        alert(line);
                    }


                });

            });
```

@Eddie - MSFT
thank u for ur answer
i used this Code
and it seems it work, but im not sure of that because it gives me back a HTML Page
[the response in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnB5b.png)
do u know what is that